# TortoiseHG icons missing (Ubuntu Linux 16)

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, mercurial, tortoisehg

Running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, with Python 2 (and I also have Python 3 installed), TortoiseHG used to show icons and text in toolbar, and I'm not sure when it happened, but now it does not show text or icons. I have install 3.8.3, but this changed nothing. Are there any other suggestions?

[image: thg missing icons]

EDIT:

I recently installed QT (https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu), thinking that I may use it. THG is also designed with QT. I also installed QGIS (http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html), and it too IS MISSING IT'S ICONS! [UPDATE]: I downloaded, built and installed QGIS from source and this corrected the QGIS problem.

EDIT2:

I followed suggestions here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1307619
which said to uninstall appmenu-qt5... but, to no avail

Comment: Can you say what icon packages are installed? Like `oxygen-icon-theme`, `breeze-icon-theme`, `adwaita-icon-theme`.

Comment: Adwaita, breeze-dark, cab_view.pngdefault.kde4, DMZ-White, handhelds, HighContrast, Humanity-Dark, LoginIcons, mate, redglass, ubuntu-mobile, ubuntu-mono-light, unity-webapps-applicationsxemacs-icon2.xbm, xemacs-icon3.xpm
breeze, cab_extract.png, defaultDMZ-Black, gnome, hicolor, Humanity, locolor, Luv, oxygen, suru, ubuntu-mono-dark, unity-icon-theme, whiteglassxemacs-icon2.xpm, xemacs-icon.xpm

Answer (score 1):

I my case the solution was doing the following steps:

1. Find where the file `thg.svg` is located:

   ```
   $ locate thg.svg
   /home/marcin/.local/share/pixmaps/tortoisehg/icons/scalable/apps/thg.svg
   ```
2. Find where `thg` is looking for icons:

   ```
   $ strace thg 2>&1 | grep thg.svg.*ENOENT
   access("/usr/local/share/pixmaps/tortoisehg/icons/scalable/actions/thg.svg", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/usr/local/share/pixmaps/tortoisehg/icons/scalable/apps/thg.svg", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/usr/local/share/pixmaps/tortoisehg/icons/scalable/status/thg.svg", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   ```
3. Copy icons to the proper location:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/pixmaps
   $ sudo cp -R /home/marcin/.local/share/pixmaps/tortoisehg /usr/local/share/pixmaps/
   ```
4. Restart `thg`

Answer (score 0):

It might be a weird config/cache issue, in which case you could try clearing the cache:
`rm -rf ~/.cache/tortoisehg` or whatever the program's cache folder is called, then restart the program.

If that doesn't work you could try to uninstall and reinstall (assuming you installed from a repo)

```
sudo apt purge tortoisehg;
sudo apt autoremove --purge;
sudo apt update;
sudo apt install tortoisehg;
```

Or you could always uninstall and then build from source, as documented by toroisehg on their site: [Running TortoiseHg 2.x from source on Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20170131215641/https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/developers/Linux)

---

If you want to do a full manual uninstall, you could try looking for TortoiseHG files and deleting them manually with `locate tortoise` which will return file paths, `rm -rf [path]` for each path.

Then try reinstalling.

Comment: Ug, thanks for the suggestions, but none of the above works. I'm thinking this is aPython or QT issue... not sure why i think that...

Comment: Based off of your first edit it probably is a QT issue. But just as a sanity check, check `/usr/share/icons/` for the missing icons to verify that the files at least exist somewhere

Comment: There are thg icons at /usr/share/pixmaps/tortoisehg/icons/ Slick Rick, if you are running thg in Ubuntu, can you verify their proper location?

Comment: That sounds right, you're probably right that it's a qt issue, not a tortoisehg issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `python-pyqt5.qtsvg` to make the toolbar icons show up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26137831)

Comment: The question is essentially "How do I get the missing toolbar icons in TortoiseHG to show up?"  Installing the `python-pyqt5.qtsvg` package enables THG to render the icons.  I am neither critiquing or requesting clarification.  I am providing a simple solution to a problem that I also encountered.